# Show that a Cayley digraph is strongly connected if and only if it is weakly connected.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Show that a Cayley digraph is strongly connected if and only if it is weakly connected.
(A digraph is strongly connected if there is a directed path between any two vertices. It is weakly
connected if the underlying graph is connected.) Hint: this is true for any regular digraph.

Comment: This holds in any graph where every vertex has the same in- and out-degrees, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2506630/81032

Comment: @DánielG., Sorry I'm a little bit new with Cayley graphs and Graph theory, You mean that in every Cayley graph which is weakly connected, every vertex has the same in- and out-degrees?

Comment: A Cayley graph (with the usual definition where its given by a group and a generating set) is always regular, and in particular it has the same in- and out-degrees. Moreover, it is always weakly (and thus strongly) connected, so your problem seems a bit peculiar. Maybe you are using a different definition of a Cayley graph?